# NTP configuration for setting past time

Tags: ntp

Try to set the time to earlier than the current time - we changed the time to 14:00 (GMT + 2) when the local time was 17:00 (gmt+2) and it didn't work but when we changed to 19:00 (gmt+2) it worked.

The question is: Is it possible that we can set the past time using ntp (Ubuntu 16.04) and it will work?

Will appreciate any comment !

Answer (score 1):

NTP is not designed to track anything except the one true time, so this setup is not guaranteed to work.

However, if you stop NTP, set your clock manually to the desired time, configure NTP with the local clock driver as its sole source, and start NTP again, it should use that time.

The clock driver selection should be as follows:

```
server 127.127.1.1 iburst prefer
fudge 127.127.1.1 stratum 0
```

And you should ensure that there are no other `peer`, `pool`, or `server` lines present in your configuration.

Note that this will make your system subject to the inaccuracies of your local clock, which is not recommended.

Note also that NTP always works in UTC, so the local time zone has no relevance.  It's used for display only.